# YOLOv2 input image size

Tags: yolo

I want to train YOLO on custom objects for detection gender from surv camera stream.
I see that default YOLO input layer is 416x416, should I stick to this or maybe it could be better have bigger size for input images for ex. 640x480 etc.
(Original image size could be from 2 to 4 MPx)